# Why is my index in my enumerate() function not functioning properly?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, enumerate, customtkinter

So when I'm trying to make buttons for my sidebar, I make a button for every class by using a for loop.

```
for index, course in enumerate(api.pull_courses('insert_my_api_key_which_works')):
            course_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text=course,
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame('ClassPage' + str(index)))
            print(index)
            course_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=((index + 1) * ((0.6)/9))+0.2, anchor=customtkinter.CENTER)
```

The `print(index)` function gives the output

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

but the `command=lambda: controller.show_frame('ClassPage' + str(index))` keeps trying to class `ClassPage7` instead of `Classpage0`, `ClassPage1`, etc.
Does anybody know why or have a fix for future reference?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To fix it create the `lambda` this way:

```py
command=lambda index=index: controller.show_frame("ClassPage" + str(index))
```

Comment: it will probably work, because it breaks the dynamic binding that makes all callbacks point to the same `index`